# Are there Vue schematics?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to vue so I'm wondering if there's something I can leverage to help me automate/scaffold some common Vue activites. I'm talking about creating components, creating a vue-router,etc.

Angular has something like this build into it's Angular CLI. (e.g. `ng generate c my-component` will generate a sub-folder named '/my-component' folder and add 3 files in there with some pre-written code). This helps speed up development. Now I do like how concise Vue is and it's not that difficult to create components etc. But I wanted to ask to see if I'm missing something obvious.

Please be kind I'm new to vue and quite frankly npm as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Vue has a command line interface (CLI) that can help you automate common tasks when working with Vue. The Vue CLI is a npm package, so you can install it by running the following command:

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

Once you have the Vue CLI installed, you can use it to create a new Vue project and other related tasks

```
vue create my-project
cd my-project
vue generate component MyComponent
vue add router
```